# Dynamic SQL SQL Server 2012 Get Result into a #temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. I will like to get final result from @sql into a temp table.Here is my code so far. Thanks for your help.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#MY_DT_CTE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MY_DT_CTE
CREATE TABLE #MY_DT_CTE
([ROWID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)
,[YYYYMM] INT
)
; WITH MY_DT_CTE AS
(
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1),112)) AS [YYYYMM]
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2),112)) AS [YYYYMM]
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-3),112)) AS [YYYYMM]
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-4),112)) AS [YYYYMM]
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-5),112)) AS [YYYYMM]
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-6),112)) AS [YYYYMM]
)
INSERT INTO #MY_DT_CTE
SELECT [YYYYMM] FROM MY_DT_CTE
ORDER BY [YYYYMM] DESC;
-- SELECT * FROM #MY_DT_CTE

DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(YYYYMM)
FROM (SELECT p.YYYYMM FROM #MY_DT_CTE AS p
GROUP BY p.YYYYMM) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
SELECT p.YYYYMM FROM #MY_DT_CTE AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
COUNT(YYYYMM) FOR YYYYMM IN ('
+ STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1,
'')
+ ')
) AS p;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Need to bring this result @sql into a temp table.
201605  201606  201607  201608  201609  201610

Comment: a temporary table is only  visible for the current connection.

Comment: would the EXEC sp_executesql  cause a new context so the previous #Temp table would no longer be visible?

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to use a global temporary table. This can be `selected into` in the dynamic SQL scope to automatically have the desired schema and still be available after that exits.

```
SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
INTO ##GlobalTemp
FROM
(
SELECT p.YYYYMM FROM #MY_DT_CTE AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
COUNT(YYYYMM) FOR YYYYMM IN (' + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT *
FROM   ##GlobalTemp
```

However this can cause issues with naming clashes if the code is ever executed concurrently.

It is possible to use a local temp table but the code is more involved as it involves creating a temp table at the upper scope and then using dynamic SQL to alter it to the dynamically determined schema before inserting into it.

```
CREATE TABLE #T
  (
     Dummy INT
  );

SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #T ADD   Dummy2 INT' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@columns, 'p.', ''), ']', '] int') + ';
            ALTER TABLE #T DROP COLUMN Dummy, Dummy2;'

EXEC (@sql);

SET @sql = N'
INSERT INTO #T
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
SELECT p.YYYYMM FROM #MY_DT_CTE AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
COUNT(YYYYMM) FOR YYYYMM IN (' + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '') + ')
) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT *
FROM   #T
```

Comment: Martin Smith,
I have tried both approaches above.
approach 1. ##GlobalTemp does not get created.

Comment: approach 2. #T  only has original column in it with no values in table.

Comment: @Nas_Gon looks like you probably integrated it incorrectly then. It relies on `@columns` being populated as in your example code. as here http://rextester.com/KCM23794

Comment: Martin Smith,
Thanks for the results as shown in link above @rextester.com
It works great.
Best Regards. Nas_Gon